# I tried to make an alternative that tells the user if the number he has chosen is the right one, above it or under it

Tags: javascript

A number is randomly chosen and I want it to appear in my console.log at line 29, so that the following alternative can work. For the moment, whether I type down a number lower or higher than the ramdom one, the text of the first part of my alternative is the one that applies. Can someone help?

```js
window.addEventListener("load", genererNbAleatoire)

//Valeurs que vous pouvez utiliser pour les verdicts
const min = 0;
const max = 100;
let nb = min + (max - min + 1) * (Math.random());

//J'ajoute mes écouteurs d'évènement
document.getElementById('btnGo').addEventListener("click", verifierNombre);
document.getElementById('btnReset').addEventListener("click", reinitialiserJeu);
document.getElementById('btnNbEssais').addEventListener("click", connaitreNbEssais);

//Je déclare mes variables globales
nombreChoisi = document.getElementById('btnGo').innerHTML;
champErreur = document.getElementById("error").innerHTML;
champInfo = document.getElementById("info").innerHTML;

//Fonction qui retourne un nombre aléatoire entre un min et un max
function genererNbAleatoire(min, max) {
  console.log(Math.floor(nb))
  return Math.floor(nb);
}

function verifierNombre() {
  //console.log('bouton verifierNombre fonctionnel')
  if (nombreChoisi < nb) {
    console.log(nombreChoisi)
    this.champErreur = "Le nombre est trop petit"
    console.log(this.champErreur)
  } else {
    this.champErreur = "Le nombre est trop grand";
  }

}

function reinitialiserJeu() {
  //console.log('bouton reinitialiserJeu fonctionnel');
}

function connaitreNbEssais() {
  //console.log("bouton connaitreNbEssais fonctionnel");
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btnGo" value="Vérifier nombre">
<input type="button" id="btnReset" value="Réinitialiser jeu">
<input type="button" id="btnNbEssais" value="Connaitre nombre d'essais">

<p id="error" class="erreur"></p>
<p id="info"></p>
```

Comment: `nombreChoisi = document.getElementById('btnGo').innerHTML;` should go inside the - `verifierNombre()` function so it is updated each time.

Comment: `nombreChoisi` is an empty string. Comparing `nb` to it will always result in `true`. Are you sure you meant to compare the `innerHTML` of the `btnGo` element to the randomly generated number?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.